# How do I make a command in Discord bot in js that insert data in a database with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, sequelize.js

I'm working on a Discord bot using node.js modules and Sequelize to database, and I want to add a command that users type and the bot registers them in database. This is the code so far:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { User } = require('discord.js');
const tableData = require('../config/tableData');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('Registro')
    .setInfo('Cria uma conta bancária no nosso banco de dados!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
      function insertData() {
        const newData = tableData.create({
          name: `${User.id}`,
          saldo: 0,
          farm: false,
      });
      return newData;
    }
    await interaction (insertData());
  },
};
```

But I really don't know why it's not working. First I have one file for the creation of database and the definition of the table to use, but when I export both, my bot throws an error that says it is not able to connect to my database. So I created a single file for each one and tried to connect, but honestly, I have no idea what I have to do.

Comment: Is it intentional that `const newData = tableData.create({` does not have `await`?

Comment: What do you mean? Like, I actually don't understand async functions and how it works, if I put await on const maybe will work?

Comment: You could simply frgot to indicate it. Though it all depends on how `interaction` works